# cron schedule table is empty after truncate

Tags: magento2, php, email, cron, transactional-mail

in my website send mail is not working so I truncated the cron_schedule table (before there are entries about sales order emails), the reason I truncated because the admin panel wasn't loading its working now, now when I order anything this table not getting any values. please tell me what should I do.
before I don't think my cron is not working properly, when I run crontab -l    nothing comes. because I am new to Magento I don't know how these cron runs.
*I install Magento using setup wizard so I don't really install cron
I will share you my website you can check if you want
http://zahratalebtsama.ae/
http://zahratalebtsama.ae/mail_test.php

I JUST WANT TO SEND MY TRANSACTIONAL EMAIL INSTANTLY before it was pending in this table

if anyone tell me to edit any file please just tell me the path also it will very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send order email instantly then change below setting

> Store > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Asynchronous sending = Disable

Disable Asynchronous sending and then check.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I don't recommend using sync email sending, imagine your transactional email service fail, you have a 500 error for your visitor. If it's slow, you slowdown your success page rendering too.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your cron job in the server. To configure the cron job please follow the command Or you can check the doc too.
Documentation url: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Commands are as follow
Navigate to your magento installation directory.
php bin/magento cron:install [--force]

php bin/magento cron:run
Run the above command twice.
Your cron job successfully configured.
Now you can have your schedules data into the table.

Comment: i run this commands first and i got too many values in the table, but in the second time i run cron:run it only says killed and nothing happens, now how can i run this pending crons in that table

Comment: after doing this now my I/O Usage
1 MB/s / 1 MB/s (100%) i cant access admin panel or website

Comment: Something is killing the system usage. Also you don't have to run that cron command again and again. You need to initialize that for once. What's the Ram size of your server?

Comment: 512mb, now i get email from cpanel like this   "bin/sh: line 1: 515897 Killed                  /opt/alt/php73/usr/bin/php /home/qvgp0nn2q341/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/qvgp0nn2q341/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log"

Comment: Your server doesn't meet the basic requirements for magento 2. You need atleast 2GB of Ram to work properly with Magento 2.

Comment: ok, I will upgrade it, is there any way to execute all these pending cron jobs in this table with this 512 MB RAM. now in this table has 21,823 values